# Access to input value having the java bean property name

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a variable which value is the name of one java bean property.

I can access this element with ${name}. Using ${name} the jsp displays "jbName" but I want to access to the java bean value.

Example:

jbName has the value "Value"

I need the jsp to write "Value" instead of "jbName".

Comment: JSPs don't deal with "inputs". They deal with Java beans and HTTP requests.

Comment: So, is it the name of a Java bean property, or the name of an attribute. If the former, where is the Java bean stored? If the latter, where is the attribute stored (in the page, the request, the session or the application?)

Comment: it is the name of a java bean property. in my bean i have a field called "name".  in the request i have the bean and the name of the property ("name"). i need to access the value of the property "name" of the java bean. i dont´t know the name of the property, i get it from the request

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the bean is stored in an attribute called `someBean`, and the property is stored under an attribute called `name` all you need is

```
${someBean[name]}
```

You seem to confuse fields and properties. Fields are never accessed directly by the JSP EL. The above will in fact access a public getter `getName()`.